# EPSG:900913 x display as EPSG:4326

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver

I have a question when the projected EPSG::4326 and EPSG::900913. 
OpenLayers uses by default EPSG::4326 using the projection coordinates in decimal format already uses Google Maps with coordinates EPSG::900913 meters.

I saw several examples of creating the map in the projection and display property EPSG::900913 projection in EPSG::4326.

What difference does it make on the map? If I want to record a point in the database will be in the map projection EPSG::900913 in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Display projection is for controls that display coordinates to the user, such as the MousePosition control. It has no effect on the map.

If you want to extract the position of a point on the map using code, it will be in the map's native projection, in this case EPSG900913.